# Remove the unused indexes from RPGLE Array

Tags: rpgle

I have a `RPGLE` subprocedure that returns an array of dim(100) as output. When the array is not filled completely, I am seeing the blanks in unused indexes. I need to get rid off those trailing blanks and return only the array indexes with values.

```
Dcl-Pr SubProc char(10) dim(100);

End-Pr
```

Is it possible in RPG IV?

Answer (score 1):

Why does this matter? You defined the array with 100 elements, and that is what is going to be passed. You cannot define a variable length array to be returned. You can either process the array until you find a blank row, or you can return the array and count of rows in parameters like this:

```
dcl-pi *n;
  array     char(10) dim(100);
  length    int(5);
end-pi;
```

Or, come to think of it, you can return a data structure that contains an array and length like this:

```
dcl-ds rtnds_t  Qualified Template;
  length        int(5);
  array         char(10) dim(100);
end-ds;

dcl-pi *n likeds(rtnds_t);
end-pi;
```

Then process the returned data structure in a for loop.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I knew i could process until the blank or get the length, but I needed to get rid off the unused indexes. Is it impossible to do get rid off the unused array indexes in RPG ?

Comment: You can only pass a fixed length array. RPG does not have variable length arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned it seems that a list is what is really wanted.

There are some list implementations in RPG, f. e.

- https://bitbucket.org/m1hael/llist - Linked List
- https://bitbucket.org/m1hael/arraylist - Arraylist

Depending on what you want to do with the data you should choose either one or the other, see http://blog.rpgnextgen.com/blog/2017/02/19/lists-arraylist-vs-linked-list .

Documentation: http://iledocs.rpgnextgen.com and http://iledocs.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php?program=/QSYS.LIB/FIST1.LIB/QRPGLESRC.FILE/LLIST.MBR (for as along as the new ILEDocs is not generated for Linked List)

Examples: http://rpgnextgen.com/index.php?content=examples

Answer (score 0):

You can remove trailing blanks in an array by returning a varchar array.  However you'd still be returning the entire array.

```
DCL-PR dan1 varchar(10) dim(100);
end-pr;
```

...

```
mArray(1) = 'Hello';
mArray(2) = ' World';
   for k = 3 to %element(myArray);
      %len(mArray(k)) = 0;
   endfor;
return mArray;
```

Comment: With SQL a table with only used rows could be returned from a procedure.  You could go that way.  With Java my 2nd favorite part of java is the list functions.  You could return a list of some type inculding only the used rows.

Comment: np   @SadamHusain

Answer (score 0):

[IBMi Rest Web Services - Part3](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-rest-web-services-server3/index.html)

```
dcl-ds wrapperDS qualified;
   ArrayName char(1) dim(999);
   ArrayName_LENGTH int(10);
end-ds;

for i = 1 to ArrayName_LENGTH;
   //Process each array entry in the loop
   println(ArrayName(i));
endfor;
```